# Selecting same row of multiple listview controls at the same time

Tags: vb.net, listview

In my application I have a form that contains 5 different listview controls.  I am trying to achieve two things here which I have become a little stuck on...

**1.** Is there a way I can make it so when I click on row 3 (for example) of Listview1, it selects row 3 for all listview controls?  I have the following code set in my _SelectedIndexChanged event of Listview1 which works correctly, however, I want to make it so if the user clicks on row3 of any listview, it changes all listview controls to row 3.

```
Private Sub lsvRegisters_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lsvRegisters.SelectedIndexChanged
    Try
        If Not lsvRegisters.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
            Dim index As Integer = lsvRegisters.SelectedIndices(0)

            If lsvRegister_Hardware.Items.Count > 0 Then lsvRegister_Hardware.Items(index).Selected = True
            If lsvRegister_Software.Items.Count > 0 Then lsvRegister_Software.Items(index).Selected = True
            If lsvRegister_Processes.Items.Count > 0 Then lsvRegister_Processes.Items(index).Selected = True
            If lsvRegister_System.Items.Count > 0 Then lsvRegister_System.Items(index).Selected = True
            If lsvRegister_Misc.Items.Count > 0 Then lsvRegister_Misc.Items(index).Selected = True
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        CreateLog("Module: lsvRegisters_SelectedIndexChanged()" & vbNewLine & "Exception Error: " & ex.Message)
        MsgBox("Exception Error: " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Module: lsvRegisters_SelectedIndexChanged()")
    End Try
End Sub
```

And secondly:

**2.** Is there a way I can make it so all listview controls have the highlight bar as active colour?  Currently it only shows the focused listview control with a blue highlight bar and the others in a dull grey.  I want to (if possible) have all listview controls show in blue regardless if it has focus or not.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

**Update**
The multiple selection of listview controls is now working as requested, however, once a listview loses focus, it only keeps the first cell highlighted as shown below:

[image]

My code for setting up the listview controls comes from a dataset.  I have demonstrated the first listview, but all of them are the same.

```
        Try
            QueryString = "SELECT * FROM Registers WHERE StoreID = '" & _StoreCode & "'"
            Dim ExQry As New MySqlCommand(QueryString, MySQLConn)

            Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(ExQry)
            da.Fill(dsStoreDetail, "StoreDetail")
            Dim tempDT As DataTable = dsStoreDetail.Tables("StoreDetail")

            If dsStoreDetail.Tables.Count > 0 And dsStoreDetail.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
                For x = 0 To (dsStoreDetail.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1)
                    Dim lvi_RegistersItem As ListViewItem = lsvRegisters.Items.Add(tempDT.Rows(x)("Online").ToString)
                    lvi_RegistersItem.SubItems.Add(tempDT.Rows(x)("Lane").ToString)
                    lvi_RegistersItem.SubItems.Add(tempDT.Rows(x)("Host_Name").ToString)
                    lvi_RegistersItem.SubItems.Add(tempDT.Rows(x)("Reg_Type").ToString)
                    lvi_RegistersItem.SubItems.Add(tempDT.Rows(x)("Operator").ToString)
                    lvi_RegistersItem.SubItems.Add(tempDT.Rows(x)("Register_Locked").ToString)

                Next
            Else
                lblEmptyString.Visible = True
            End If
            dsStoreDetail.Clear()
            tempDT = Nothing

        Catch ex As Exception
            CreateLog("Module: LoadStoreData()" & vbNewLine & "Exception Error: " & ex.Message)
            MsgBox("Exception Error: " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Module: LoadStoreData()")
            lblEmptyString.Visible = True
        End Try
```

I have set all listview controls to FullRowSelect = True but only at design time - not sure if that matters.

Comment: I recommend you to only put one question at a time. This way you are more likely to get an answer. Since someone who knows one answer might not know the other one. And since they are unlikely to get the "Accepted response" with only one answer they say nothing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, this is my conclusion for this and it will be made with things named differently from yours, I'm afraid.

To Start off, setup all ListViews to have theese settings:

```
HideSelection = True
MultiSelect = false
```

This is what I have placed in all ListViews selected Index changed.

```
Private Sub ListView2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView2.SelectedIndexChanged
    If Not Working And ListView2.SelectedIndices.Count <> 0 Then
       UpdateAllListViewes(ListView2.SelectedIndices)
    End If
End Sub
```

Working is a Private Boolean that is used to avoid unecessary calls to the UpdateAllListViews function. UpdateAllListViews sends all listboxes to the UpdateSelectedIndex function with the Index to light up. As you can see the Working Boolean is updated to True while this executes. This can be skipped, but debugging will turn into a nightmare if something goes wrong.

```
Private Sub UpdateAllListViewes(ByVal Indexes As ListView.SelectedIndexCollection)
        Working = True
        UpdateSelectedIndex(ListView2, Indexes(0))
        UpdateSelectedIndex(ListView3, Indexes(0))
        UpdateSelectedIndex(ListView4, Indexes(0))
        UpdateSelectedIndex(ListView5, Indexes(0))
        Working = False
    End Sub
```

And finally how to update the selected indexes:

```
Private Sub UpdateSelectedIndex(ByVal lv As ListView, ByVal Index As Integer)
    For i As Integer = 0 To lv.Items.Count - 1
        If i = Index Then
            lv.Items(i).Selected = True
            lv.Items(i).BackColor = Color.DodgerBlue
            lv.Items(i).ForeColor = Color.White
        Else
            lv.Items(i).Selected = False
            lv.Items(i).BackColor = Color.White
            lv.Items(i).ForeColor = Color.Black
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

DodgerBlue is the SelectedIndex color for a ListView. This should solve both question 1 and 2.

Comment: thankyou so much for your reply and very sorry to include two questions under the one topic.  I will remember this for future.  Your above example works a treat except for one minor issue... When I click on a listview it will select the entire row within that listview, but only the first column within the others. So I don't end up with a complete row selected, only bits from all of them.

Comment: Is "FullRowSelect" True on all of them?

Comment: Yes it is. If I click on a particular listview it will highlight the full row - it only highlights cell 1 when I click on a different listview.  Would you like a screen capture?

Comment: Yes please, and preferably code containing how you set up your ListViewItem

Comment: Thanks WozzeC.  I have updated my thread.  One thing I forgot to mention was that my listview has OwnerDrawn=True set.  I manually populate the DrawColumnHeader, DrawItem and DrawSubItem routines but leave everything else automatic.

Comment: Ok fixed.  I set the HideSelection=False on all listview controls and the issue is now fixed - strange.  Anyway, thankyou for your help with everything WozzeC - greatly appreciated.

Comment: Odd, when I had HideSelection=False it only would allow me to have grey selections. Ahwell, good thing it got sorted.

Answer (score 0):

i found usefull the others answers, but tried to another way, and founded usefull this way as simple it´s:

```
Private Sub ListView2_ItemSelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles ListView2.ItemSelectionChanged
    If Not (e.IsSelected) Then
        ListView3.Items(e.ItemIndex).BackColor = Color.White
        ListView4.Items(e.ItemIndex).BackColor = Color.White
        ListView5.Items(e.ItemIndex).BackColor = Color.White
    Else
        ListView3.Items(e.ItemIndex).BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue
        ListView4.Items(e.ItemIndex).BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue
        ListView5.Items(e.ItemIndex).BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue
    End If

End Sub
```

For every time that u pick an item on the listview, the code will light the others listview items in same index.

for example `Handles ListView2.ItemSelectionChanged` handle the event.

`Not (e.IsSelected)` ask for the type of selection.

Then u give a color `ListView3.Items(e.ItemIndex).BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue`

The function `.IsSelected` return a boolean that represent an action like "it's selected, or it's unselected", well you only need to give the old color to resently unselected items.. and a new color to the new selection. Good luck!!